# NSColor: colorWithDeviceRed... is not working on second monitor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, color-space, nscolor

In order to be able to calibrate a monitor, I must be able to drive it in device RGB values.

In order to do this I create a NSColor by:

```
[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:(colorsPtr[cnt]/255.0f) green:(colorsPtr[cnt+1]/255.0f)
blue:(colorsPtr[cnt+2]/255.0f) alpha:1.0]
```

And then I put this Color on the View.

```
[colorView setColor:[colorsForMeasuring objectAtIndex:index]];
```

When I use the "DigitalColor meter", this device color is only applied without any conversion when the View is shown on the primary monitor. So only on the monitor that has the menu bar on it.

In case you put the view on your second monitor, it looks as if there happens a conversion from RGB of main display to RGB of the second display. You only see this if there is a big difference between gamuts of both displays. I have a MacBook Pro with an Eizo ColorEdge CG 245 for example. If you then put [0 0 1.0] you might get something like [0.2 0.1 1.0].

Anyone an idea how to get rid of this extra conversion. Up to my opinion deviceRGB should be deviceRGB. In order to make a profile for the second monitor, this is mandatory. Now I have to move the menubar to the second monitor, create the profile and move it back. But with our application customers need to be able to do a validation and this needs to be done frequently. And the same problems occurs here.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug to me. I suggest [reporting it](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

As a workaround, you might try implementing a custom view in which you respond to `drawRect:` by calling `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` and `CGContextFillRect`. (You can [get the CGContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSGraphicsContext/graphicsPort) from [the current NSGraphicsContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSGraphicsContext/currentContext).)

Comment: Same problem with CGContextSEtRGBFillColor: (100, 0, 0) -> (100, 12, 0), (0, 100, 0) -> (0, 100, 0), (0, 0, 100) -> (24, 0, 100). Only pure green remains pure.

Comment: @user850121: Sounds like a bug I reported (7542845) about using an old Apple Studio Display (LCD) as my main display. Blue made it the most obvious, painfully so; I'd attached a screenshot of Deus Ex, a blue-heavy game, looking very purple. I still suggest filing a bug of your own, noting within it your different circumstances (external display).